# Timeout value in Python 3 urlopen?

Tags: python, python-3.x, timeout, urlopen

I am have a small crawler and I am extracting a web-page content of a simple page.

```
def url2dict(url):
    '''
    DOCSTRING: converts two-column data into a dictionary with first column as a key.
    INPUT: URL address as a string
    OUTPUT: dictionary with one key and one value

    '''
    with urlopen(url) as page:
        page_raw = page.read()
        ...
```

Now this function calls the server at url. The problem is the server has generated 504 Error

```
File "C:\Python38\lib\urllib\request.py", line 222, in urlopen
    return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "C:\Python38\lib\urllib\request.py", line 531, in open
    response = meth(req, response)
  File "C:\Python38\lib\urllib\request.py", line 640, in http_response
    response = self.parent.error(
  File "C:\Python38\lib\urllib\request.py", line 569, in error
    return self._call_chain(*args)
  File "C:\Python38\lib\urllib\request.py", line 502, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "C:\Python38\lib\urllib\request.py", line 649, in http_error_default
    raise HTTPError(req.full_url, code, msg, hdrs, fp)
urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 504: Gateway Time-out
```

My problem is I cannot find what is the default value of urlopen timeout.

Here https://bugs.python.org/issue18417 it is said that there is no timeout (timeout = None) by default (at least for Python 3.4 version):

> OK, I reviewed the issue enough to remember:  If socket.setdefaulttimeout is never called, then the default timeout is None (no timeout).

What is the current state for 3.8?

If there is no timeout set, why I got this error of Error 504?

More details:

One of the errors shows error in

```
 File "C:\Python38\lib\urllib\request.py", line 222, in urlopen
    return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
```

I open the file and I have read:

> def urlopen(url, data=None, timeout=socket._GLOBAL_DEFAULT_TIMEOUT,
>               *, cafile=None, capath=None, cadefault=False, context=None):
>       '''Open the URL url, which can be either a string or a Request object.

```
*data* must be an object specifying additional data to be sent to
the server, or None if no such data is needed.  See Request for
details.

urllib.request module uses HTTP/1.1 and includes a "Connection:close"
header in its HTTP requests.

The optional *timeout* parameter specifies a timeout in seconds for
blocking operations like the connection attempt (if not specified, the
global default timeout setting will be used). This only works for HTTP,
HTTPS and FTP connections.
```

So does **(if not specified, the global default timeout setting will be used)** mean that if I have a global variable defined called **timeout**, it  would be used as a timeout duration?

Comment: `HTTP Error 504: Gateway Time-out` AFAIK hints to: 'The server you requested does not have the document himself and requested it elsewhere. But this request took to long for the first server aka gateway`.

Comment: HTTP 504 response is not generated by your code (timeout of your request), you have gotten that from the server you've made the request to. https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-6.6.5 - 
*"The 504 (Gateway Timeout) status code indicates that the server,
   while acting as a gateway or proxy, did not receive a timely response
   from an upstream server it needed to access in order to complete the
   request."*

Comment: Is there a way to mitigate that error? Apart of error handling, of course.

For example, to make a second request after some cooling time?

Answer (score 1):

Your research was actually correct, default timeout is determined from `socket._GLOBAL_DEFAULT_TIMEOUT`. To learn its value, you can use  [`socket.getdefaulttimeout()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/socket.html?#socket.getdefaulttimeout):

> Return the default timeout in seconds (`float`) for new socket objects. A value of `None` indicates that new socket objects have no timeout. When the socket module is first imported, the default is `None`.

TL;DR by default there is no timeout set.

The timeout you're seeing is a response from the server as per the [RFC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.6.5):

> The 504 (Gateway Timeout) status code indicates that the server,
> while acting as a gateway or proxy, did not receive a timely response
> from an upstream server it needed to access in order to complete the
> request.

The machine you're making a request against is a front that can be for instance a (reverse) proxy serving content from another server, e.g. to balance loadbalance between multiple back-end servers.

Being on the server side, you cannot do much about it except for perhaps catch the problem and if you know / believe it is intermittent re-try.